# Time and coordinates: how can I find this result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Longitude,latitude,time
0,1,1
0,1,2
0,1,3
2,4,4
2,5,5
2,4,6
```

My result is: 0,1,1 1 time because they are consecutives and 2,4 2 times because they aren't consecutives in terms of time. How do I calculate this result?

Comment: What is your question?  It is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need to supply a column to order the result by

Comment: There are 6 points in my table. If a point is consecutive in terms of time I want a count of one. 0,1 count=1. If a point is not consecutive with another I want a count of two. The point 2,4 has a count of two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, I can’t test as on iPad, Also the -9999 is not perfect, this needs to not be in your data.

```
Select x.lat,x.lng,sum(case when lat=nextlat and lng=nextlng then 0 else 1 end ) s
From
(    Select lat,
            lng,
            lead(lat,1,-9999) over (order by time) nextlat ,              
             lead(lng,1,-9999) over (order by time) nextlng
     From table
) x
Group by x.lat,x.lng
```

Comment: No the order by is in the lead. I added it. Time isn’t in your final select. Did the query work, I am just using eyes